# libsodium build warnings

Tags: stake-pool, cardano-node

I am working to set up a Cardano staking pool (node).  As I was building the specific [reference of libsodium called out in the docs](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/installing-cardano-node#downloading--compiling) (66f017f1), I got a LOT of unsettling warnings such as (truncated):

```
In file included from crypto_kx/crypto_kx.c:8:
#warning *** This is unstable, untested, development code.
#warning It might not compile. It might not work as expected.
#warning It might be totally insecure.
#warning Do not use this except if you are planning to contribute code.
#warning Use releases available at https://download.libsodium.org/libsodium/releases/ instead.
#warning Alternatively, use the "stable" branch in the git repository.
```

Is this normal/okay???

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The version of libdsodium's code you are compiling is the one used by the majority of Stake Pool Operators (SPO) as it is the reference in all official How-To.

These simple warnings are normal because, as you may have noticed with the url, it is [an **intentional** forked repository maintained by IOHK](https://github.com/cardano-community/guild-operators/issues/421). But don't worry, it works perfectly with the latest releases of cardano-node.